# c# sql insert. Use of unassigned local variable?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ado.net, sql-server-ce

My application is saying totalTokens is use of an unnassigned local variable and I am not seeing why. I must be missing something obvious. Here is the line. Full code is below. 
Thanks

```
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Tokens", totalTokens);



    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string date = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
        bool library = chkLibrary.Checked = true;
        string libReason = txtReason.Text;
        int libMin = Int32.Parse(txtLibTime.Text);
        int hwMin = Int32.Parse(txtHwTime.Text);

        int partialTokens;
        int totalTokens;
        int totalHw;

        // calculate Total homework
        totalHw = libMin + hwMin; 

        // calculate bonus library time
        partialTokens = totalHw / 15;

        // calculate Total tokens
        if (chkLibrary.Checked == true)
        {
            totalTokens = partialTokens + 1;
        }

        using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conString))
        {
            SqlCeCommand myCommand = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO ChangeTable" + 
            "(Date, Library, LibMissed, LibTime, HwTime, TotalHomework, Tokens)" +
            "VALUES(@Date, @Library, @LibMissed, @LibTime, @HwTime, @TotalHomework, @Tokens)", con);

            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Date", date);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Library", library);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@LibMissed", libReason);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@LibTime", libMin);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@HwTime", hwMin);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@TotalHomework", totalHw);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@TotalHomework", totalTokens);

            con.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            RefreshGrid();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`totalsTokens` will only be assigned if `chkLibrary.Checked` is `true`. If it is `false` then it would remain unassigned.

Answer (score 4):

The `totalTokens` variable is only assigned a value if the condition in the `if` statement is true. You have to make sure that the variable always has a value.

Perhaps you meant something like:

```
// calculate Total tokens
if (chkLibrary.Checked == true)
{
  totalTokens = partialTokens + 1;
} else {
  totalTokens = partialTokens;
}
```

Side note: When you use the variable, you are assigning two values to the same parameter, which will of course overwrite the first value:

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@TotalHomework", totalHw);
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@TotalHomework", totalTokens);
```

Judging from the parameters used in the query, it should be:

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@TotalHomework", totalHw);
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Tokens", totalTokens);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (chkLibrary.Checked == true)
        {
            totalTokens = partialTokens + 1;
        }
```

this is the only time totalTokens is assigned to..... so if `chkLibrary.Checked` isn't checked, then it's an unassigned variable.

Not sure what you want it to be by default?  but perhaps when you declare it you want

```
int totalTokens = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Wheres this line on your code

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Tokens", totalTokens);
```

you should have this between myCommand initialization and con.Open();

Answer (score 1):

`totalTokens` is only initialized inside that conditional; thus it's not guaranteed to be set when you call `myCommand.Parameters.Add("@TotalHomework", totalTokens);`.

Just initialize it to something (like 0) where you declare it, and the warning should go away.

Answer (score 1):

The fix is basically assign it SOME kind of value when you create it,  for example

```
int partialTokens = 0;
int totalTokens= 0;
int totalHw = 0;
```

Currently, it is possible it will be used without having a value assigned, due to the assignment inside a conditional statement.